# determining a linux filesystem drives types in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm totally new to powershell, and still in the very basics, I'm not planning to waste lot of time on it, because I do have work to do and I have a goal to achieve, I wonder if there is any command that is similar to the command `df -Th` in linux.

I want the result to show ext*, basically I wonder if there is a way to distinguish a linux drive in powershell.

---

my goal is to automount every linux drive to wsl2 with no interaction from me in the powershell, is that possible?

forgive my lack of knowledge in windows, I'm a mac and linux guy, but curiosity is a key for learning.

Comment: `Get-PSDrive` seems to be the most equivalent, but I could probably think of about 7 ways to get the information you're looking for using powershell. `Get-Drive` is also a relevant one.

Comment: I would suggest saving yourself the trouble of writing all this, when you could just google for similar questions. To include searching on here using the powershell tag

Comment: It look like I'm the first to ask, I couldn't find any questions like mine, however, `Get-Drive` didn't work in my PS for some reason as it said it didn't find it, `Get-PSDrive` did work, but it has a long output that I mostly didn't understand or relate to my goal as of `ext4`.

Comment: What should your output look like then?

Comment: I don’t mind any structure of lists, table, json, xml or whatnot as long as I get a Linux filesystem type when available, such as ext4/3/2 MSDos and other types

Comment: If you are talking about mounting physical *ext\** drives to WSL, you'll need the in-development version from the Insiders ring.  Either Dev or Beta (as of a few days ago) should have that feature.  Not quite sure about the PowerShell aspects, but see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) for more information that might help.  Also, as a side note, consider whether [Super User](https://superuser.com) might be a better place for this question, since it seems to be more about "configuration" than "programming".

Comment: I have the windows 11 Dev channel insiders preview, I usually mount it manually for each device, but sometimes when you have something that won’t work on windows it becomes tedious to redo the same thing over and over, that is why I would like to automate it, but you’re right, I probably should ask there as it’s a configuration not programming, thanks for the help.